# ¿ Cómo hacer esto cuando aprietas un botón?

Tags: java, android

sé cómo pasar a una activity cuando aprietas un botón o que salgan Toast pero... me hace falta que cuando apriete un botón me salga un editText y pueda poner un numero , es decir que me salgan tantos editText como veces pulse yo el botón..

Comment: Deberías cambiar el titulo para que sea más descriptivo.

Answer (score 1):

Tienes que crear los `EditText` dinámicamente

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);

final LinearLayout edits = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.edits);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText edit = new EditText(getBaseContext());
        edit.setHint("EditText");
        edit.setHintTextColor(Color.GRAY);
        edits.addView(edit);
    }
});
```

En la vista están el botón y un `LinearLayout`

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"/>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/edits"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"/>
```